# Linux detects Vaio touchpad as a ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse

Tags: linux, mouse, fedora, touchpad, sony-vaio

I tried this on Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Fedora. My problem is that in these distros, my Vaio VPCSA touchpad is detected as a normal mouse. It works as a simple mouse but multitouch gestures, double finger tap as right-click and disabling touchpad with **Fn** + **F1** features do not work.

Here are two screenshots from KDE System Settings:
[image]
[image]

```
$ xinput list 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]                                                                                                                        
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]                                                                                                                        
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]                                                                                                                        
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]                                                                                                                        
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]                                                                                                                        
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]                                                                                                                        
    ↳ Sony Vaio Keys                            id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]                                                                                                                        
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]                                                                                                                        
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]                                                                                                                        
    ↳ USB2.0 Camera                             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]                                                                                                                        
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]

$ dmesg | grep touchpad
[    1.253474] psmouse serio1: alps: Unknown ALPS touchpad: E7=73 03 50, EC=73 02 02
[ 1834.326946] psmouse serio1: alps: Unknown ALPS touchpad: E7=73 03 50, EC=73 02 02
[18253.349035] psmouse serio1: alps: Unknown ALPS touchpad: E7=73 03 50, EC=73 02 02
[19030.731439] psmouse serio1: alps: Unknown ALPS touchpad: E7=73 03 50, EC=73 02 02
[33156.487845] psmouse serio1: alps: Unknown ALPS touchpad: E7=73 03 50, EC=73 02 02

$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -i name
N: Name="Lid Switch"
N: Name="Power Button"
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
N: Name="ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse"
N: Name="Video Bus"
N: Name="Video Bus"
N: Name="USB2.0 Camera"
N: Name="Sony Vaio Keys"
N: Name="Sony Vaio Jogdial"
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
```

Comment: I've to fix this problem recently, check this page for a new driver that support this touchpad https://github.com/he1per/psmouse-dkms-alpsv7